# WSO2 ESB Managment Console - Change header

Tags: wso2-esb

Is there a way to change the "WSO2 ESB Management Console" header text from "Management Console" to something else for ex "MC PROD 1" or something else.

We would need that sicne we are running several WSO2ESB instances and it's sometimes confusing to know on what server we are logged in to.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can change the context of the url of each instances. that is in the carbon.xml, default is     `<WebContextRoot>/</WebContextRoot>` . Where you can provide descriptive strings to identify the diffrent nodes.

```
eg:     <WebContextRoot>/esb</WebContextRoot>
<WebContextRoot>/as</WebContextRoot>
```